# Error when user enters time from keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, input, time

User enters time from keyboard. I have limited the keyboard so that the user can only type in the correct time. But still jumps into the `else` case from time to time (although when checking the input times are still correct). My app has users from many countries so I think there is a problem here.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hhmma"
dateFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
    
var AMorPMStart = ""
if startTimeAMPMSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
    AMorPMStart = "PM"
}else {
    AMorPMStart = "AM"
}
    
var startDate = Date()
    
if let _ = dateFormatter.date(from: startDateHourString + startDateMinuteString + AMorPMStart) {
    startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: startDateHourString + startDateMinuteString + AMorPMStart)!
}else {
    AlertService.showInfoAlert(in: self, title: StringForLocal.error, message: StringForLocal.invalidStartTime)
    return
}
```

I have tested a lot of time input cases but it seems to be wrong only for certain set of users. On my device everything is fine.

Comment: Why not use a system built-in picker like `UIDatePicker`?

Comment: show a complete example that does not work. Include the user input string, where you get the error and the full error message.

Comment: Forcing users to type in a time in a fixed format that is likely unusual for them is not the best user experience.